# Как правильно разыменовать const wchar_t*?

Tags: c++

Создаю переменную
`const wchar_t* text = L"Текст";`

Пытаюсь ее разыменовать `std::cout << *(text);`
Но на выводе получаю **1057**. Не подскажете, почему так? И как тогда правильно разыменовать?

и можно ли как-то установить кодировку, чтобы выводились русские символы?

Comment: А что Вы хотите получит после разыменования?

Comment: Сразу ascii текст

Comment: `std::wcout << text;`

Comment: Вы неверно понимаете, что такое разыменование...

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае строка `wchar_t` это массив, следовательно `text` - указатель на его первый элемент. Когда вы его разыменовываете, то получаете значение, хранящееся в первой ячейке (*char-код* первого символа).

Если вам нужно вывести всю строку на консоль, используйте:

```cpp
std::wcout << text;
```

---

Как вывод понимает, что строка закончилась? У массива ведь нельзя узнать длину? В общем, да, но строки это особый случай. Когда вы создаете строку, то она превращается в массив размером **количество символов + 1** и на последнем месте ставится `\0` (символ с кодом 0). Теперь длину строки можно определить исходя из положения *нуль-терминатора* (для этого даже есть функция `strlen()` в библиотеке `cstring`).

---

Предлагаю вам подумать, чему будет равняться длина строки (с точки зрения C++)

```cpp
"Hello\0world!"
```

Comment: Это все хорошо, а теперь напишите ответ для широких символов, кои идут в вопросе.